# Shuffle pandas dataframe n times and rename it each time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to shuffle a pandas dataframe 'n' times and save the shuffled dataframe with a new name and then export it to a 'csv' file. What I mean is-

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
```

Then something like this-

```
for i in np.arange(n):
    df_%i = shuffle(df)
    df_%i.to_csv('example.csv')
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
for i in range(n):
    df.sample(frac= 1).to_csv(f"example_{i}.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks very much, @S_Ymln, it really helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create an arbitrary number of variables, you should store them in a dictionary and you can reference them later by their keys; in this case the integer you loop over.

```
d = {}
for i in range(n):
    d[i] = df.sample(frac=1)  #d[i] = shuffle(df) in your case
    d[i].to_csv(f'example_{i}.csv')
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 3)))

d = {}
for i in range(5):
    d[i] = df.sample(frac=1)

d[1]
#   0  1  2
#0  6  3  2
#1  7  6  4
#2  2  6  9

d[2]
#   0  1  2
#2  2  6  9
#1  7  6  4
#0  6  3  2
```

Comment: Thanks very much @ALollz, it really helps.